# How connect multiply databases ( hsqldb, mysql ) with DB setting in separate files

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, maven-3, hsqldb

Basically I want to decide with which of 2 databases project will run.

I have following  **hibernateContext.xml**

```
  <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
 </bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.blog.przem.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>

    </property>
</bean>
```

And **database.properties** file

```
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pbdb
jdbc.user=root
jdbc.password=
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to add HSQLDB to my project (for development, testing) but for production I want to have MySQL DB. 
I already seen some solutions:

- in spring config file [[Can I use HSQLDB for junit testing cloning a mySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607665/can-i-use-hsqldb-for-junit-testing-cloning-a-mysql-database)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607665/can-i-use-hsqldb-for-junit-testing-cloning-a-mysql-database)
- in maven http://www.manydesigns.com/en/portofino/portofino3/tutorials/using-maven-profiles-and-resource-filtering

I wondering what is best approach, but I would like to keep databases settings in separate files.

1. Should I create **database.properties2** file (with HSQL properties) and add **propertyConfigurer2**? And how to make dataSource bean to know  which **propertyConfigurer** to use (I have feeling that I miss something)?
2. Maybe it should be done by maven?
3. What is professional approach to such problem (assuming that project finaly will use MySQL) - application should always use MySQL, and HSQLDB should be used only for running tests classes?

Comment: Is your project a web application?

Comment: @Ralph Yes, it is web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ralph answer works nice and as I was told it is good solution for bigger projects, and I have been given another solution how to resolve my problem so many databases can be set for project and tests files without creating additional applicationContext-db.xml ( however I don't know if having separate configuration xml's for tests is better than aproach presented below)

That code for slighty changed  my **hibernateContext.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.blog.przem.entity" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>
        </props>

    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

1. PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer was extracted (with removed id="propertyConfigurer") to new file **proprtiesContext.xml**
   (of course    was added to **hibernateContext.xml**)

   ```
   <beans profile="default">
       <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
           <property name="locations">
               <list>
                   <value>classpath:msql_database.properties</value>
               </list>
           </property>
       </bean>
   </beans>

   <beans profile="testing">
       <bean  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
           <property name="locations">
               <list>
                   <value>classpath:hsql_database.properties</value>
               </list>
           </property>
       </bean>
   </beans>
   ```
2. Then I modified and added configuration files for both databases:

**msql_database.propertie**

```
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pbdb
jdbc.user=root
jdbc.password=
jdbc.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

**hsql_database.propertie**

```
jdbc.driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem;shutdown=true
jdbc.user=sa
jdbc.password=
jdbc.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

Now if I run (in my case Tomcat) server it using **"default"** - nothing special - MYSQL database is used
But if I run server with parameter

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="testing"
```

It using given profile so my project using HSQLDB HOORAY

Additionally when I add specific profile in test class (just before class name declaration):

```
 @ActiveProfiles("default")
public class UserServiceTest {
```

Specified database is used for testing

Answer (score 1):

So I would recommend that the server provide the database connection via JNDI.

In additon you need to define the Database Dialact. Therefore I would recommend to use a Server Parameter.

For the test cases I would use an other database configruation file, that does not use jndi, but configure the database like you need it for your tests.

---

For example in Tomcat: Context.xml (global or better application specific context.xml)

```
<Resource name="jdbc/yourApp" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pbdb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"

    auth="Container"
    username="" password="geheim"

    maxIdle="3" maxActive="15" maxWait="10000" logAbandoned="true" removeAbandoned="true"

    removeAbandonedTimeout="60" validationQuery="select 1" />

<Parameter name="yourApp.database.dialect" value="mysql" override="false" />
```

Spring: `applicationContext-db.xml` in `src\main\resources`

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/yourApp"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.blog.przem.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${yourApp.database.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>

    </property>
</bean>
```

Now your are able to configure the application on every application server with an different database.

For Database-"integration" Tests based on Spring I would put an test specific `applicationContext-db.xml` without jndi and dialect property placeholder in `src\test\resources` (it "overrides" the normal one for the tests).

@See this answer for some additional information [Spring Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283653/spring-configuration/6902999#6902999) - it describes an other way of how to name `applicationContext-db.xml` for the tests.